# How to generate Insert statement from PGAdmin4 Tool?

Tags: pgadmin-4

We are writing a new application, and while testing, we will need a bunch of dummy data. I've added that data by using MS Access to dump excel files into the relevant tables into the Postgres database.

What should I do now to generate an Insert statements from the PGAdmin4 Tool similar to what SQL Studio allow us to generate an Insert statements for SQL Server? There are no options available to me. I can't use the closest one, which is to export and import the data via CSV.

Comment: Can you share why can't you use the closest one? You can use the [COPY command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html) to copy data from the csv files

Comment: in pgAdmin4 you can open context menu by right clicking your table on: [Database name] > Schemas > Tables > [Table name]. In context menu go to: Scripts > INSERT Script Or Import/Export Data and choose your CSV file in dialog

Comment: I need these insert statements so that I can use it to seed the data from the ASP.Net core Entity framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand that you cannot import the CSV file into the actual DB as this needs to be done through ASP.NET core EF. Perhaps, you can probably create a test schema and import the CSV file into the test schema. Once you have the data imported into the test schema, you can use that to generate SQL statements using the steps below:

- Right click on target table and select "Backup".
- Select a file path to store the backup. You can save the file name as data.backup
- Choose "Plain" as Format.
- Open the tab "Options" check "Use Column Inserts".
- Click the Backup-button.
- Once the file gets generated you can open with Notepad++ or VSCode to get the SQL insert statements
- You can use the statements generated and delete the test schema created

Here is a resource that might help you in loading data from Excel file into PostgresSQL if you still need to take this path [Transfer Data from Excel to PostgreSQL](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/postgresql-excel-trans.rst#:%7E:text=Transfer%20Data%20from%20Excel%20to%20PostgreSQL%201%20Establish,data%20from%20an%20existing%20spreadsheet%20in%20Excel.%20)

Comment: A couple of comments probably related to specific of the current version 7.5 of pgAdmin 4 about the steps above:
1) Instead of the "Options" tab use "Table Options".
2) In Windows it saves implicitly to the Documents.